# Visual Studio 2008 Floating Windows Are Offscreen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

My block of floating windows in Visual Studio 2008 (output, error list, find results, etc) are gone -- offscreen I assume.

I haven't been able to find a keyboard shortcut for the options (floating window equivalent of Alt-Space for real windows). How can I get my floating windows back?

Answer (score 9):

Select to **Window > Reset Window Layout**, and agree to the *Are you sure you want to...?* prompt.

The price you pay is giving up your old window layout (including docked windows).
The benefit you get is... your floating windows back. And those are useful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an equivalent for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for Visual Studio tool windows.  There are a couple of other ways which should fix this though.

First option is to reset your window layout.  This should bring them back on screen

- Window -> Reset Window Layout

Other option is to reset all of your settings.  This will bring you back to a default profile which should reset the tool windows

- Tools -> Import / Export settings
- Reset Settings